# Breaking long number literal into multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Breaking long *string* literals into multiple lines is not problem, e. g.

```
long_string = ("This is a very very long string literal for writing it as one-line "
               "literal. More appropriate is using more lines so that the code" 
               "will be more readable.")
```

But what about long *integer* literals, e. g.

```
long_number = 12312323456782556897455666645555554787825401568014564565678978201245667185
```

Is there some similar possibility?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
long_numer = int("1231232345678255689745"
                 "5666645555554787825401"
                 "5680145645656789782012"
                 "45667185")
```

As long as this is not in your hot codepath, the extra step should not cause issues.

Answer (score 4):

In python, there is no max value for an integer. If you really want to do something like this, you can try

```
x = '12312323456782556897455666645555554787825401568014564565678978201245667185' \
    + '12312323456782556897455666645555554787825401568014564565678978201245667185'
```

Now, to fetch the value, you can simply do

```
long_number = int(x)
```

Except for Pep8, you are not really achieving much by doing this though.

Another way you can parse the value could be using `ast`

```
import ast

long_number = ast.literal_eval(x)
```